# Why does SymPy not simplify (-x**3)**(2/3) to x**2?

Tags: python, sympy, exponent

I'm trying to use SymPy to evaluate the following integral:
[image: $$ \int_{lower}^{0} $$]

When evaluating by hand, the answer is −½ log(28).

My work matches up with SymPy until I integrate with respect to `x`:

```
x, y = sp.symbols('x y', real=True)
z = 1 / (sp.root(y, 3)*(x**3+1))
iz = z.integrate((y, -x**3, 0)) # integrate with respect to y
print(iz)
# -3*(-x**3)**(2/3)/(2*(x**3 + 1))
iiz = iz.integrate((x, 0, 3)) # integrate with respect to x
print(iiz)
# -3*Integral((-x**3)**(2/3)/(x**3 + 1), (x, 0, 3))/2
print(sp.N(iiz))
# 0.833051127543801 - 1.4428868782084*I
```

It seems what’s throwing SymPy off is `(-x**3)**(2/3)`. This should simplify to `x**2` but SymPy doesn’t think so. Manually simplifying, produces the same answer I got by hand:

```
print( sp.integrate(-3*x**2/(2*(x**3 + 1)), (x, 0, 3)) )
# -log(28)/2
```

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: I had a quick look at https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html#powers at the simplifications not performed by default but unfortunately none of them changed anything.

You should probably inquire on github https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Comment: The `abs()` match.  `iiz` has a `(-1)**(2/3)` term, which makes the result complex.

Comment: @hpaulj The observation about `abs()` was really interesting. Does this mean `-log(28)/2` and `0.833051127543801 - 1.4428868782084*I` are both valid answers because they are both the same distance away from the origin in the complex plane?

Comment: @nvi: While −½ log(28) and 0.83 − 1.44 i are correct answers, this is not because they have the same absolute value (distance to the origin). It’s only a required property that comes from the special properties of this particular equation. There are infinitely many numbers with that property and at most three of them are solutions (depending on what definition of the ^⅓ in your equation is, whether you allow complex solutions and so on). Moreover, for other problems, solutions may have different absolute values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that `sympy.root` by default returns the principal root, not the real root. To avoid this, you can use the third optional argument of `sympy.root` to specify that you would like the real root. The following produces the desired result:

```
import sympy as sp

x, y = sp.symbols('x y', real=True)
z = 1 / (sp.root(y,3,1)*(x**3+1))
iz = z.integrate((y, -x**3, 0))
iiz = iz.integrate((x, 0, 3))
print(iiz)
# -log(28)/2
```

To somewhat address your titular question, `(-x**3)**(2/3)` is actually `(-x**3)**0.666666666666667` because that’s a Python fraction you have there. To have something closer to what you want, you need to do:

```
import sympy as sp
x = sp.symbols('x', positive=True)
solution = (-x**3)**sp.Rational(2,3)
print(solution)
# (-1)**(2/3)*x**2
```

In general, I would recommend to avoid rational powers unless you really need to account for them in all their multiple solutions, complexity, etc.

Comment: Running your first snippet shows sp.N(iiz) = -1.6661022550876 + 2.71050543121376e-20*I. That's closer to the answer I'm expecting since sp.N(-sp.log(28)/2) = -1.66610225508760 but I'm not clear on where that tiny imaginary part comes from. From my understanding, complex numbers don't have an equivalent real form so I'm confused that i'm getting two different answers to the same problem.

Comment: @nvi: I cannot reproduce that. The first code returns `-log(28)/2` to me, which `sympy.N` turns into `-1.66610225508760`.

Comment: Interesting, this might have something to do with Colab using Sympy version 1.1.1. I've copied your code [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12dK-c5xFRbNHXwwz9be4cZJPyq04llrh?usp=sharing). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In my `isympy` session:  SymPy 1.6.2

```
In [131]: z = 1 / (root(y,3)*(x**3+1))

In [132]: iz = z.integrate((y, -x**3, 0))

In [133]: iiz = iz.integrate((x,0,3))

In [134]: iiz
Out[134]: 
     2/3         
-(-1)   ⋅log(28) 
─────────────────
        2        

In [135]: N(iiz)
Out[135]: 0.833051127543801 - 1.4428868782084⋅ⅈ

In [136]: abs(iiz)
Out[136]: 
log(28)
───────
   2
```

The `root` docs talk about returning the principal root, and in addition to providing a `k` parameter, suggest using `real_root`:

```
In [137]: z = 1 / (real_root(y,3)*(x**3+1))

In [138]: iz = z.integrate((y, -x**3, 0))

In [139]: iiz = iz.integrate((x,0,3))

In [140]: iiz
Out[140]: 
-log(28) 
─────────
    2    

In [141]: N(iiz)
Out[141]: -1.66610225508760
```

So evidently the double integral has multiple solutions, depending on the root.  Looks like they all have the same magnitude.  That sounds reasonable, but my complex math studies were in the distant past, so I can't provide a theoretical justification.

and with `k=2` we get a third solution:

```
In [146]: z = 1 / (root(y,3,2)*(x**3+1))

In [147]: iz = z.integrate((y, -x**3, 0))

In [148]: iiz = iz.integrate((x,0,3))

    In [149]: iiz
    Out[149]: 
    3 ____        
    ╲╱ -1 ⋅log(28)
    ──────────────
          2
```

So there are 3 solutions in the complex plane, with multipliers, `-1, (-1)**(1/3), -(-1)**(2/3)`, and the same magnitude.

```
-1.66610225508760
0.833051127543801 - 1.4428868782084⋅ⅈ
0.833051127543801 + 1.4428868782084⋅ⅈ
```

If we introduce an integer symbol `k` into `z`:

```
In [158]: z = 1 / (root(y,3,k)*(x**3+1))

In [159]: z
Out[159]: 
      -2⋅k    
      ─────   
        3     
  (-1)        
──────────────
3 ___ ⎛ 3    ⎞
╲╱ y ⋅⎝x  + 1⎠
```

the double integral becomes:

```
In [164]: iiz =z.integrate((y, -x**3,0)).integrate((x,0,3))

In [165]: iiz
Out[165]: 
             -2⋅k          
             ─────         
     2/3       3           
-(-1)   ⋅(-1)     ⋅log(28) 
───────────────────────────
             2
```

and doing `iiz.subs({k:0})` etc, produces the above complex solutions.